# How to set the default activemq 5.10.0 configuration file?

Tags: activemq-classic

Hello,

In hope to configure correctly my apache activemq my Ubuntu I followed the tutorials from

http://servicebus.blogspot.com/2011/02/installing-apache-active-mq-on-ubuntu.html

Everything worked just fine I started the broker and stopped it. Now I tried to start it back with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/activemq start
```

I then have this output

```
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties       to get details
INFO: changing to user 'leo' to invoke java
INFO: pidfile created : '/opt/activemq/data/activemq-leo-Aspire-5742G.pid' (pid '22579')
```

Running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/activemq status
```

I get

```
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
ActiveMQ not running
```

What I truly find odd is that when I move to

```
/opt/apache-activemq-5.10.0
```

and issue the command

```
./activemq start
```

It returns

```
ERROR: There are syntax errors in '/etc/default/activemq'
```

So I deleted the **/etc/default/activemq** file and ran **./activemq start** once again and here it runs once again.

```
    INFO: Using default configuration
(you can configure options in one of these file: /etc/default/activemq     /home/leo/.activemqrc)

INFO: Invoke the following command to create a configuration file
./activemq setup [ /etc/default/activemq | /home/leo/.activemqrc ]

INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Process with pid '22810' is already running
```

---

Below is my present erroneous configuration file. How should I configure the configuration file?

```
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Configuration file for running Apache Active MQ as standalone provider
    #
    # This file overwrites the predefined settings of the sysv init-script
    #
    # Active MQ installation dir
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_HOME" ] ; then
    # try to find ACTIVEMQ
    if [ -d /opt/activemq ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_HOME=/opt/activemq
    fi

    if [ -d "${HOME}/opt/activemq" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_HOME="${HOME}/opt/activemq"
    fi

    ## resolve links - $0 may be a link to activemq's home
    PRG="$0"
    progname=`basename "$0"`
    saveddir=`pwd`

    # need this for relative symlinks
    dirname_prg=`dirname "$PRG"`
    cd "$dirname_prg"

    while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> (.*)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '.*/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
    else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
    fi
    done

    ACTIVEMQ_HOME=`dirname "$PRG"`/..

    cd "$saveddir"

    # make it fully qualified
    ACTIVEMQ_HOME=`cd "$ACTIVEMQ_HOME" && pwd`
    fi

    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_BASE" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_BASE="$ACTIVEMQ_HOME"
    fi

    # Active MQ configuration directory
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_CONF" ] ; then

    # For backwards compat with old variables we let ACTIVEMQ_CONFIG_DIR set ACTIVEMQ_CONF
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_CONFIG_DIR" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_CONF="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/conf"
    else
    ACTIVEMQ_CONF="$ACTIVEMQ_CONFIG_DIR"
    fi
    fi

    # Configure a user with non root priviledges, if no user is specified do not change user
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_USER" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_USER="leo"
    fi

    # Active MQ data directory
   if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_DATA" ] ; then

    # For backwards compat with old variables we let ACTIVEMQ_DATA_DIR set ACTIVEMQ_DATA
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_DATA_DIR" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_DATA="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/data"
    else
    ACTIVEMQ_DATA="$ACTIVEMQ_DATA_DIR"
    fi
    fi

    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_TMP" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_TMP="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/tmp"
    fi

    setCurrentUser(){
    CUSER=`whoami 2>/dev/null`

    # Solaris fix
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    CUSER=`/usr/ucb/whoami 2>/dev/null`
    fi
    }

    if [ ! -d "$ACTIVEMQ_DATA" ]; then
    setCurrentUser
    if ( [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_USER" ] || [ "$ACTIVEMQ_USER" = "$CUSER" ] );then
    mkdir $ACTIVEMQ_DATA
    elif [ "`id -u`" = "0" ];then
    su -c "mkdir $ACTIVEMQ_DATA" - $ACTIVEMQ_USER;
    fi
    fi

    # Location of the pidfile
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_PIDFILE" ]; then
    ACTIVEMQ_PIDFILE="$ACTIVEMQ_DATA/activemq-`hostname`.pid"
    fi

    # Location of the java installation
    # Specify the location of your java installation using JAVA_HOME, or specify the
    # path to the "java" binary using JAVACMD
    # (set JAVACMD to "auto" for automatic detection)
    #JAVA_HOME=""
    JAVACMD="auto"

    # Set jvm memory configuration
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms1G -Xmx1G"
    fi

    # Uncomment to enable audit logging
    #ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS -Dorg.apache.activemq.audit=true"

    # Set jvm jmx configuration
    # This enables jmx access over a configured jmx-tcp-port.
    # You have to configure the first four settings if you run a ibm jvm, caused by the
    # fact that IBM's jvm does not support VirtualMachine.attach(PID).
    # JMX access is needed for quering a running activemq instance to gain data or to
    # trigger management operations.
    #
    # Example for ${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access:
    # ---
    # # The "monitorRole" role has readonly access.
    # # The "controlRole" role has readwrite access.
    # monitorRole readonly
    # controlRole readwrite
    # ---
    #
    # Example for ${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password:
    # ---
    # # The "monitorRole" role has password "abc123".
    # # # The "controlRole" role has password "abcd1234".
    # monitorRole abc123
    # controlRole abcd1234
    # ---
    #
     ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
     ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
     ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
     ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
    ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"

    # Set jvm jmx configuration for controlling the broker process
    # You only have to configure the first four settings if you run a ibm jvm, caused by the
    # fact that IBM's jvm does not support VirtualMachine.attach(PID)
    # (see also com.sun.management.jmxremote.port, .jmx.password.file and .jmx.access.file )
    ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_CONTROL="--jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/jmxrmi --    jmxuser leo --jmxpassword leo"
    #ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_CONTROL=""

    # Specify the queue manager URL for using "browse" option of sysv initscript
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_QUEUEMANAGERURL" ]; then
    ACTIVEMQ_QUEUEMANAGERURL="--amqurl tcp://localhost:61616"
    fi

    # Set additional JSE arguments
    ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS="$SSL_OPTS"

    # Uncomment to enable YourKit profiling
    #ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS="-agentlib:yjpagent"

    # Uncomment to enable remote debugging
    #ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -    Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"

    # ActiveMQ tries to shutdown the broker by jmx,
    # after a specified number of seconds send SIGKILL
    if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_KILL_MAXSECONDS" ]; then
    ACTIVEMQ_KILL_MAXSECONDS=30
    fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your script, its possible your issue is here:

```
-    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
```

Use have spaces between your -  and Dcom.  These are JVM arguments and should not have a space between the - and D:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
```

That may have been a copy and paste format issue, but the error you presented doesn't give much to look at.  Make sure the other arguments after that also have no spaces between the flag and the D.

As far as the process already running is concerned, it looks like you had started ActiveMQ already.

You can use the following command to determine if its running if the script is not working for you:

```
ps -ef | grep activemq
```

I would recommend following documentation on http://activemq.apache.org/ rather than the link you followed if you are just learning ActiveMQ.  There is much more to configure and understand beyond what was mentioned in that post.  It makes things a bit more complicated than they need to be if you are just learning.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is because in the /activmq script under Using instances there are someif else statements, if the file is not found it redirects to a default file, open the script and look

see here for more info

[Unix configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html)

happy coding !